# TestFlight upload failed

Tags: ios, testflight, ios6.1

I have successfully created a .ipa file using XCode but now I cannot upload it.
The upload just stalls randomly.

**I'm using the  TestFlight desktop app**

Here are some screenshots :

- While uploading :
  [image]
- After a short while, this comes up :
  [image]

Comment: its already given you the solution, you connection get breaked during the upload, try again

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to check if this is not an issue of the TestFlight uploader. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: check if you got the most recent version.

Comment: @ShamsAhmed it's the most recent version of their desktop app.

Comment: Does your upload make it to 100%? How long until the 'Upload failed' appears? What is your Internet connection like? Does this happen every time or just occasionally?

Comment: @RobertKleinsasser every single time. it halts. about 2 minutes after halting. could it be my network connection/configuration ? or something else?